# How can I detect a close in the browser tab?

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, browser

Hello I am looking for information on the close tab (not browser) event if there is one in java for a applet. I am wondering if there is an event for that or a way to check a way to check for that. I would like to just capture the event and make a little popup box , stating Your session will expire or something along those lines. Is that possible at all or to a point with java or Javascript?

UPDATE: okay with the information you guys pointed me into i was able to get information on a simple enough javascript. Now it is working fine in IE , Chrome and Firefox but for some reason Safari 5.1.7 isn't liking the code. Not sure why. Here is the code if it helps.

```
jQuery(function() {
var hiddenBtn = document.getElementById("javaform:browserCloseSubmit");

try{
    opera.setOverrideHistoryNavigationMode('compatible');
    history.navigationMode = 'compatible';
}catch(e){}

//Sends the information to the javaBean.java file. 
function ReturnMessage()
{
    return hiddenBtn.click();
}

//UnBind Function
function UnBindWindow()
{
    jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload', ReturnMessage);
}



//Bind Exit Message Dialogue
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', ReturnMessage);

});
```

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same...

Comment: I think he means with an applet (java) or using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercept page exit event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

Comment: You should look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185105/how-to-detect-the-windownew-tab-close-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `onBeforeUnload` event you can catch in JavaScript. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event).

Comment: Thank you,It seems to mostly work but safari seems to be giving me some issues. Is there another method I can use for safari besides return?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Are you sure you want to exit?";
};
```

Note that it will also end in *Are you sure you want to leave this page* (or *are you sure you want to reload this page* if you are reloading)